# Get posts by user role in a Multisite

Tags: multisite, query-posts

Currently, I can only get the post by user roles on specific sites. What I need is to have a query that will get the post from user role on other site.

```
Example Users:
Site A - user(admin site a, editor site a)
Site B - user(editor site b)
Site C - user(editor site c)
```

> Site A - index list of posts
>
> - Post by admin site A
> - Post by editor site A
>
> Site B - index list of posts
>
> - post by admin site A
> - post by editor Site B.
>
> Site C - index list of posts
>
> - post by admin site A
> - post by editor Site C.

Comment: have you tested my code with multiple conditions. & addrestore_current_blog() at last

Answer (score 0):

```
global $switched;
switch_to_blog(2); //switched to your site id based on which site post need.

$administrators = get_users( array( 'role' => 'administrator' ) ); // you can add more role on same query add with "," separated.
$administrators_ids = array();

$original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); 


foreach( $administrators as $admin ):
    $administrators_ids[] = $admin->ID;
    $news = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => implode( ',', $administrators_ids ), 'post_type' => 'news', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) );
endforeach;
    if ( $news->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $news->have_posts() ) : $news->the_post();

            //add code here

        endwhile; 

    endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: It only shows the admin post and the switch_to_blog should be dynamically

Comment: yes need to add more code as per your conditions.
change role & site id which you wnats.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 //admin posts from main site:
    switch_to_blog(get_main_site_id());
 $admin_posts =   get_posts_by_user_roles(array('role'=>'administrator'));
    restore_current_blog();

    //editor posts from current blog
 $editor_posts =   get_posts_by_user_roles();
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($admin_posts);
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<br>";
 echo "<br>";
 print_r($editor_posts);
 exit;

function get_posts_by_user_roles($args = array()) {
     $args = wp_parse_args( $args,  array( 'role' => 'editor', 'fields'=>"ID" ) );
       $users = get_users($args);
       if(empty($users))
       {
           echo "No users found";//print for debug purpose only
           return FALSE;
       }
       return get_posts( array('author' => implode(',', $users), 'post_type' => 'post' ) );

}
```